# WPF Data binding alternate datacontext inside Itemscontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

What I'm trying to do is bind the controls generated by a `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate` to a new instance of my `ContactInterface` class that is created whenever I run my query function.

**ContactInterface.cs**

```
class ContactInterface : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Type { get; set; }

    private string firstname;
    public string FirstName { 
        get{return this.firstname;}
        set {
            if (this.firstname != value) {
                this.firstname = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("FirstName");
            }
        }
    }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
}
```

**SQL.cs**

```
partial class MainWindow
{
    private void selectContact(int? contactID)
    {
    using (ContactsDataContext context = new ContactsDataContext("Data Source=ds;Initial Catalog=db;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        Contact contact = context.Contacts.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ContactID == contactID);
        Contact spouse = context.Contacts.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ContactID == contact.Spouse);
        Property property = context.Properties.SingleOrDefault(x => x.PropertyID == contact.Address);

        ContactInterface selectedContact= new ContactInterface();

        selectedContact.FirstName = contact.FirstName;

        profileGrid.DataContext = selectedContact;
    }

 }
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xaml
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ItemsControl Name="Profile_Page_Controls">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="15">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="43" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="43" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="43" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="43" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="43" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="43" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="43" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="43" />

                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                </Grid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TextContent}"/>
                    <TextBox Height="23" Text="{Binding Path=FirstName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding profile_Column}" />
            <Setter Property ="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding profile_Row}" />
            <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="{Binding profile_Colspan}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
    <CheckBox Name="profile_SpouseCheck" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,0" Checked="profile_SpouseCheck_Checked_1" Unchecked="profile_SpouseCheck_Checked_1"> Spouse</CheckBox>


</Grid>
```

My plan is to make a new `ContactInterface` instance every time a user runs the `selectContact()` function. That new instance will be bound to the generated controls, so when the user makes and saves a change, the textboxes will update that `ContactInterface` instance and my other functions can grab the data from that `ContactInterface` to make changes to the database. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

`ContactInterface`? The word interface has a specific meaning in programming and it just feels wrong here.

---

`this.NotifyPropertyChanged("FirstName");`: avoid magic strings, [use a lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1316566/648075).

---

Your use of brackets is inconsistent: sometimes they are on the same line (e.g. `if (this.firstname != value) {`), other times they're on a new line. Stick to the second style, which is the common C# way.

---

Avoid indentation when possible. Instead of this:

```
  if (this.firstname != value) 
  {
     this.firstname = value;
     this.NotifyPropertyChanged("FirstName");
  }
```

Do this:

```
 if (this.firstname == value) 
 {
    return;
 }

 this.firstname = value;
 this.NotifyPropertyChanged("FirstName");
```

---

`SQL.cs` contains the code for `MainWindow`? In any case, SQL.cs isn't a good class name anyway, since [it violates naming rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/141e06ef%28v=vs.71%29.aspx): "When using acronyms, use Pascal case or camel case for acronyms more than two characters long."

---

This is becoming an unmanageable mess:

```
<Grid Margin="15">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="43" />
        <RowDefinition Height="43" />
        <RowDefinition Height="43" />
        <RowDefinition Height="43" />
        <RowDefinition Height="43" />
        <RowDefinition Height="43" />
        <RowDefinition Height="43" />
        <RowDefinition Height="43" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

It will become complicated to keep track of which element is where, so consider alternative UI elements, e.g. the StackPanel.

---

`private void selectContact(int? contactID)`: methods should be Pascalcase.

---

I'm a bit surprised by this:

```
context.Contacts.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ContactID == contact.Spouse);
context.Properties.SingleOrDefault(x => x.PropertyID == contact.Address);
```

Because if `Spouse` and `Address` are ID fields, it doesn't look like it from reading this code. Which is confusing. I'd expect an ID field to be named `somethingID`. `Spouse` and `Address` look like strings containing a name or even better a related class.

---

You should really consider [adding layers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27251713/wpf-architecture-with-business-layer-and-dal) to [separate your concerns](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/75082/Layers-Pattern-in-Practice) (a `ContactsDataContext` in your `MainWindow`? Bad!). Also look into [using MVVM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx).

Comment: I agree, my naming horrible at best and things like the bracket spacing are just things I haven't gotten around to cleaning up yet. I realize that makes your job harder, and I really should of done that before I posted. 

I took out a lot of code from my original post because I felt it strayed from the real problem I'm having, Which is binding the `ContactInterface` instance to the `ItemControl`.

Comment: Also, I am using a Grid instead of a StackPanel because, unless I'm mistaken, I could not have multiple controls in the the same _row_ without creating another StackPanel. And if I opted for multiple StackPanels, I wouldn't be able to stretch controls across multiple panels, would I?